# Custom Spring Boot Oauth2 exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

In my spring boot application, I have a rest controller with methods that use a WebClient to send requests to an external api, and that endpoint uses oauth for authentication. My issue is related to throwing custom exceptions. Within the WebClient, I can throw custom exceptions based on the http status code that's returned. For example, if I send a GET request with a non-existent ID, I can handle the 404 NOT FOUND that is returned just fine.

My issue is figuring out how to throw custom exceptions resulting from the authentication endpoint being unavailable. Currently, if I send a GET request and the authentication endpoint is down, a 404 NOT FOUND is returned from the authentication endpoint, which causes a ClientAuthorizationException to be thrown, and ultimately a response with a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR http status is returned by the method in my rest controller, along with the stack trace. How do throw a custom exception in this case?

For reference, here is the configuration code I use to create the WebClient bean with the oauth included. It was originally taken from a blog at okta.com.

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta.token-uri}") String token_uri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-id}") String client_id,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-secret}") String client_secret,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope}") String scope,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrantType

    ) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("okta")
                .tokenUri(token_uri)
                .clientId(client_id)
                .clientSecret(client_secret)
                .scope(scope)
                .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(authorizationGrantType))
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("okta");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Also for reference, here is how I am throwing errors in my service. When the service throws the custom exception, a global exception handler intercepts the exception and gracefully returns a response entity with the exception message and correct http status code.

```
webClient.get()
    .uri(finalURL)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
        switch (clientResponse.rawStatusCode()) {
            case OK:
                return clientResponse
                    .bodyToMono(Resource.class);
            case NOT_FOUND:
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException(id);
            case INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR:
                throw new InternalServerErrorException();
            default:
                return Mono.empty();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [`@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-exceptionhandler.html) for `ClientAuthorizationException`.

As a side note, I'd keep a `5xx` status as what's happening actually is internal to your servers (maybe `503`?).